# React, React Router, Joy UI: How to disable snackbar re-appearing after navigating away and back?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router

I have a dummy job board web application that uses React and Joy UI for front-end and UI. I use a Joy UI's [Snackbar](https://mui.com/joy-ui/react-snackbar/)  component to temporarily pop-up a message after a user performs certain actions (registers, logs in, etc.). On the Snackbar, I set `autoHideDuration` prop to `{3000}`, so that it should dissapear after 3 seconds. The Snackbar also disappers if a user clicks on close icon or somewhere outside of the Snackbar.

However, if user, after the Snackbar appears, quickly navigates to other page and then presses "Back" button in the browser, the Snackbar re-appears and only disappears after the initial timer expires. Moreover, it looks like the timer doesn't include time a user spends on other page, so that even if a user stays on other page for more than 3 seconds, the Snackbar can re-appear after navigating back to the original page.

This is an undesired behavior, and I want the Snackbar to disappear forever if a user navigates away from the page on which the Snackbar was originally rendered.

My custom SnackBarAlert component is below:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../store/AuthContext";
import { ProfileContext } from "../store/ProfileContext";
import { FeedbackContext } from "../store/FeedbackContext";
import { SnackBarAlert } from "./SnackBarAlert";
import { Container } from "@mui/joy";

export const SnackBarContainer = () => {

    const { authStatus, changeAuthStatus } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const { profile, changeProfile } = useContext(ProfileContext);
    const { feedback, changeFeedback } = useContext(FeedbackContext);
    
    const [loggedInAlert, setLoggedInAlert] = useState(false);
    const [loggedOutAlert, setLoggedOutAlert] = useState(false);
    const [registeredAlert, setRegisteredAlert] = useState(false);
    const [editedProfileAlert, setEditedProfileAlert] = useState(false);
    const [appliedAlert, setAppliedAlert] = useState(false);
    const [postedVacancyAlert, setPosterVacancyAlert] = useState(false);
    const [editedVacancyAlert, setEditedVacancyAlert] = useState(false);
    const [deletedVacancyAlert, setDeletedVacancyAlert] = useState(false);
    const [postedFeedbackAlert, setPostedFeedbackAlert] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        authStatus.justLoggedOut && setLoggedOutAlert(true);
        authStatus.justLoggedIn && setLoggedInAlert(true);
        profile.justRegistered && setRegisteredAlert(true);
        profile.justEditedProfile && setEditedProfileAlert(true);
        profile.justApplied && setAppliedAlert(true);
        profile.justPostedVacancy && setPosterVacancyAlert(true);
        profile.justEditedVacancy && setEditedVacancyAlert(true);
        profile.justDeletedVacancy && setDeletedVacancyAlert(true);
        feedback && setPostedFeedbackAlert(true);
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <Container>
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={loggedInAlert}
                text="You successfully logged in!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setLoggedInAlert(false);
                    changeAuthStatus({
                        ...authStatus,
                        justLoggedIn: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={loggedOutAlert}
                text="You logged out!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setLoggedOutAlert(false);
                    changeAuthStatus({
                        ...authStatus,
                        justLoggedOut: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={registeredAlert}
                text="You succesfully registered! Now, please log in to your account."
                onClose={() => {
                    setRegisteredAlert(false);
                    changeProfile({
                        ...profile,
                        justRegistered: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={editedProfileAlert}
                text="You successfully edited your profile!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setEditedProfileAlert(false);
                    changeProfile({
                        ...profile,
                        justEditedProfile: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={appliedAlert}
                text="You succesfully applied for a vacancy"
                onClose={() => {
                    setAppliedAlert(false);
                    changeProfile({
                        ...profile,
                        justApplied: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={postedVacancyAlert}
                text="You successfully posted a vacancy!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setPosterVacancyAlert(false);
                    changeProfile({
                        ...profile,
                        justPostedVacancy: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={editedVacancyAlert}
                text="You successfully edited a vacancy!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setEditedVacancyAlert(false);
                    changeProfile({
                        ...profile,
                        justEditedVacancy: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={deletedVacancyAlert}
                text="You deleted a vacancy!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setDeletedVacancyAlert(false);
                    changeProfile({
                        ...profile,
                        justDeletedVacancy: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={postedFeedbackAlert}
                text="You successfully sent a message!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setPostedFeedbackAlert(false);
                    changeFeedback(null);
                }}
            />
        </Container>
    );

};
```

My SnackBarContainer that combines different alerts is below:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../store/AuthContext";
import { ProfileContext } from "../store/ProfileContext";
import { FeedbackContext } from "../store/FeedbackContext";
import { SnackBarAlert } from "./SnackBarAlert";
import { Container } from "@mui/joy";

export const SnackBarContainer = () => {

    const { authStatus, changeAuthStatus } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const { profile, changeProfile } = useContext(ProfileContext);
    const { feedback, changeFeedback } = useContext(FeedbackContext);
    
    const [loggedInAlert, setLoggedInAlert] = useState(false);
    const [loggedOutAlert, setLoggedOutAlert] = useState(false);
    const [registeredAlert, setRegisteredAlert] = useState(false);
    const [editedProfileAlert, setEditedProfileAlert] = useState(false);
    const [appliedAlert, setAppliedAlert] = useState(false);
    const [postedVacancyAlert, setPosterVacancyAlert] = useState(false);
    const [editedVacancyAlert, setEditedVacancyAlert] = useState(false);
    const [deletedVacancyAlert, setDeletedVacancyAlert] = useState(false);
    const [postedFeedbackAlert, setPostedFeedbackAlert] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        authStatus.justLoggedOut && setLoggedOutAlert(true);
        authStatus.justLoggedIn && setLoggedInAlert(true);
        profile.justRegistered && setRegisteredAlert(true);
        profile.justEditedProfile && setEditedProfileAlert(true);
        profile.justApplied && setAppliedAlert(true);
        profile.justPostedVacancy && setPosterVacancyAlert(true);
        profile.justEditedVacancy && setEditedVacancyAlert(true);
        profile.justDeletedVacancy && setDeletedVacancyAlert(true);
        feedback && setPostedFeedbackAlert(true);
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <Container>
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={loggedInAlert}
                text="You successfully logged in!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setLoggedInAlert(false);
                    changeAuthStatus({
                        ...authStatus,
                        justLoggedIn: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={loggedOutAlert}
                text="You logged out!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setLoggedOutAlert(false);
                    changeAuthStatus({
                        ...authStatus,
                        justLoggedOut: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={registeredAlert}
                text="You succesfully registered! Now, please log in to your account."
                onClose={() => {
                    setRegisteredAlert(false);
                    changeProfile({
                        ...profile,
                        justRegistered: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={editedProfileAlert}
                text="You successfully edited your profile!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setEditedProfileAlert(false);
                    changeProfile({
                        ...profile,
                        justEditedProfile: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={appliedAlert}
                text="You succesfully applied for a vacancy"
                onClose={() => {
                    setAppliedAlert(false);
                    changeProfile({
                        ...profile,
                        justApplied: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={postedVacancyAlert}
                text="You successfully posted a vacancy!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setPosterVacancyAlert(false);
                    changeProfile({
                        ...profile,
                        justPostedVacancy: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={editedVacancyAlert}
                text="You successfully edited a vacancy!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setEditedVacancyAlert(false);
                    changeProfile({
                        ...profile,
                        justEditedVacancy: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={deletedVacancyAlert}
                text="You deleted a vacancy!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setDeletedVacancyAlert(false);
                    changeProfile({
                        ...profile,
                        justDeletedVacancy: null
                    });
                }}
            />
            <SnackBarAlert
                open={postedFeedbackAlert}
                text="You successfully sent a message!"
                onClose={() => {
                    setPostedFeedbackAlert(false);
                    changeFeedback(null);
                }}
            />
        </Container>
    );

};
```

And, here is an example of my login page component that uses one of the Snackbars:

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link as RouterLink, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Typography, Card, CardContent, CardActions, Stack, Link } from "@mui/joy";
import { AuthContext } from "../store/AuthContext";
import { LoginForm } from "../components/LoginForm";
import { SnackBarContainer } from "../components/SnackBarContainer";

export const Login = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { authStatus } = useContext(AuthContext);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        authStatus.isLoggedIn && navigate("/");
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <Container>
            <Stack
                justifyContent="center"
                alignItems="center"
                spacing={5}
                sx={{ paddingY: { xs: 5, xl: 16 } }}
            >
                <Card variant="outlined" sx={{
                    width: { xs: "80%", sm: "60%", md: "40%" }
                }}>
                    <CardContent sx={{ alignItems: "center", textAlign: "center" }}>
                        <LoginForm />
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardActions>
                    </CardActions>
                </Card>
                <Typography>
                    <Link component={RouterLink} to="/candidate-register">
                        Register as a candidate here
                    </Link>
                </Typography>
                <Typography>
                    <Link component={RouterLink} to="/recruiter-register">
                        Register as a recruiter here
                    </Link>
                </Typography>
            </Stack>
            <SnackBarContainer />
        </Container >
    );
};
```

My thinking is that this issue is related to how React Router, which I use for routing, handles state in React app, but I can't find a way to solve it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

The app is live and can be accessed [here](https://job-link.onrender.com/). The full code is avaliable on GitHub [here](https://github.com/osydorchuk89/job-board).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can help resolve this a couple ways.

1. It looks like you render individual `SnackBarContainer` components where you are toasting messages. Use a `useEffect` cleanup function to set the snackbar display state if/when `SnackBarContainer` unmounts.

   ```
   export const SnackBarContainer = () => {
     const { authStatus, changeAuthStatus } = useContext(AuthContext);
     const { profile, changeProfile } = useContext(ProfileContext);
     const { feedback, changeFeedback } = useContext(FeedbackContext);

     const [loggedInAlert, setLoggedInAlert] = useState(false);
     const [loggedOutAlert, setLoggedOutAlert] = useState(false);
     const [registeredAlert, setRegisteredAlert] = useState(false);
     const [editedProfileAlert, setEditedProfileAlert] = useState(false);
     const [appliedAlert, setAppliedAlert] = useState(false);
     const [postedVacancyAlert, setPosterVacancyAlert] = useState(false);
     const [editedVacancyAlert, setEditedVacancyAlert] = useState(false);
     const [deletedVacancyAlert, setDeletedVacancyAlert] = useState(false);
     const [postedFeedbackAlert, setPostedFeedbackAlert] = useState(false);

     useEffect(() => {
       authStatus.justLoggedOut && setLoggedOutAlert(true);
       authStatus.justLoggedIn && setLoggedInAlert(true);
       profile.justRegistered && setRegisteredAlert(true);
       profile.justEditedProfile && setEditedProfileAlert(true);
       profile.justApplied && setAppliedAlert(true);
       profile.justPostedVacancy && setPosterVacancyAlert(true);
       profile.justEditedVacancy && setEditedVacancyAlert(true);
       profile.justDeletedVacancy && setDeletedVacancyAlert(true);
       feedback && setPostedFeedbackAlert(true);

       return () => {
         setLoggedOutAlert(false);
         setLoggedInAlert(false);
         setRegisteredAlert(false);
         setEditedProfileAlert(false);
         setAppliedAlert(false);
         setPosterVacancyAlert(false);
         setEditedVacancyAlert(false);
         setDeletedVacancyAlert(false);
         setPostedFeedbackAlert(false);
       };
     }, []);

     return (
       ...
     );
   };
   ```
2. Use navigation actions that maintain the history stack better. For example, assuming the `Login` component is rendered on `"/login"` and successfully authenticates, the current code then PUSHes to `"/"`. If they navigate back they land on `"/login"` again. Use REPLACE actions to help prevent poor back navigation actions so user can't navigate back to now-invalid page. The idea is to prevent users from navigating back to pages that initiated the toasts in the first place.

   Example:

   ```
   export const Login = () => {
     const navigate = useNavigate();
     const { authStatus } = useContext(AuthContext);

     useEffect(() => {
       // Redirect to "/" instead of pushing another history entry
       authStatus.isLoggedIn && navigate("/", { replace: true });
     }, []);

     ...
   };
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I tried Option 1 and added the following lines to also update the context value that triggers the rendering of  the loggedin Snackbar: `changeAuthStatus({ ...authStatus, justLoggedIn: null});`
However, when I add this to the `useEffect` cleanup function, everything breaks, and the app stops working when I try to log in. I can't figure out the reason. I only see that requests start being sent constantly to the backend.

Comment: @OleksiiSydorchuk Might be a dependency closure issue. What if you use a functional state update: `changeAuthStatus(authStatus => ({ ...authStatus, justLoggedIn: null }));`? Otherwise, has my answer here addressed/resolved the original question/issue with the toasting/navigation?

Comment: Thanks, but the updated code line also doesn't work. Can you please clarify what a dependency closure is? I'll mark the issue as resolved as I now understand how to prevent the alert from re-appearing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @OleksiiSydorchuk Javascript [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) may help explain that. The basic gist is that using the functional React state update you are updating from the current state versus whatever is closed over in the greater callback function's scope.